# Get info about computer to which Android device is connected

Tags: java, android

I have the problem. When Android device connected to computer through USB, I need to get information about this computer(such IP, Host Name or something like this). Is it really to get?

Thanks.

Comment: As this is not a TCP/IP connection I guess it is not possible. To the phone the computer looks like a mounted device (hard drive). Everything else would really surprise me... BTW: I hope you're not able to retrieve this information :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be interesting read for you:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=738

however, USB host feature has just been released and is available starting with honeycomb. this may eventually help you introduce your own communication between devices, but you'll need to write some code for PC too.

If you hope to do it directly while device is working as UMS, WMS or vendor specific portal - well, it could be possible, but this certainly will be phone specific (especially when your phone turns into multi-function device the way Motorola Droid does).

There is no typical mechanism to do that.

Answer (score 3):

As @home indicated, this is not possible.